# Find the resource pages of evaluations on human learning rate against deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, references

Maybe one year ago I read a paper about the comparison between humans and machines' learning rate. It says the human can learn fast in the beginning then get slower later, machines oppositely. I lost my search history and googled a lot but fail to find it. Hope someone can help me find the source page or give me a simple explanation about it. I remember there are some mathematical proofs behind it.

Hope I made this question clear. Thanks!